# Is possible to change functionality of "./" on linux?

Tags: linux, alias

Is there some way to use `alias ./ = "..."` or some other command for doing this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? ./ isn't a command but part of how you specify paths in bash and similar. I don't think that theres a way to change this without using a custom terminal, and don't understand why changing this would be desirable.

Comment: I have my own forensic tool and i am not sure if i can run it on computer without risk of data corruption. If there is way to do `alias ./ = "rm -rf *"`, it is no good idea to run my prgram with ./

Comment: I'm by no means a linux expert. But I don't see a way of manipulating the behavior of ./ in any linux system I've encountered in my past. Without changing the terminal itself.

Comment: yeah I do not want it too but hacker may want

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `./` works. It's not parsed by the shell, it's just part of a pathname. Nothing expands filenames into commands like `rm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in principle a function of the shell you're talking about.  Your `alias` syntax resembles the syntax for the alias commands of Bash and [the POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), so we'll start there.  I'm having trouble seeing why a conforming POSIX shell would reject

```
alias ./=...
```

to define an alias for `./`, but

1. bash 4.4 does not accept it ("bash: alias: `./': invalid alias name").  That may be a point of non-conformance, but it is of little import because
2. such an alias would not have the effect I imagine you're looking for / concerned about, because **aliases are recognized only where they appear as a whole (shell) words**.  Thus, although alias substitution might, in principle, be applied to the `./` in the command `./ ls`, an alias for `./` would not be relevant to the command `./ls`.

For a complementary view, consider tcsh 6.20.  This is a member of the csh family of shells, so not a POSIX shell, but this family also has an `alias` command, and this particular shell *does* allow you to alias `./`.  Example

```
$ tcsh
$ alias ./ echo
$ ./ foo
foo
```

But in this family, too, alias substitution is applied only to whole words:

```
$ ./foo
./foo: Command not found.
```

---

As for alternative approaches, the other potential way for someone to try to redefine a common command in a POSIX-ish shell such as Bash would be by defining a shell function with the same name.  This is not an issue for words containing the `/` character, however, because function names cannot contain that character.  (And shells in the csh family do not provide for functions.)

But if your concern is about the effect that your code may have if run on a compromised system, then there is ultimately no assurance to be had.  A sufficiently deep system compromise could replace any or all of the installed shells with customized versions, could replace the standard ELF loader with a customized version (so that compiled programs aren't safe, either), and could even replace the kernel with a customized version.

Thus, if you do not trust the system then you need to provide a whole system of your own: a bootable image with a kernel and enough tools, chosen and vetted by you, to do what you want to do.  This is akin to a rescue image: it could examine the host filesystems by mounting them, but it would not run any of the programs there.  This also has the advantage of testability.  You don't have to try to ensure that your code does the right thing in every environment, but rather only that it does the right thing in the environment you built for it.